# Trying to make a link "active" when another link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need help help editing the following JavaScript.

```
<script>
  $('.nav li a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  });
</script>
```

===================================================================

In addition to the existing functionality, I need "link2" to become "active" when "link1" is clicked. See HTML below.

```
<h1 class="brand"><a href="#link1">Brand</a></h1>
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="link2">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="link3">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="link4">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Tip: when you see `parent().parent()` you can use `parents` or `closest`.

Comment: This page on JQuery Selectors has your answer and more: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: The code you have seems to work -> http://jsfiddle.net/XZZ68/ ???

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XZZ68/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code. A [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/wLdkL/) sample is available here.

```
  $('.nav li a').on('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault(); //Add this only if you want to stop the default link action.
      $(this).parent().siblings('li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  });

  //The below is to make #link2 active whenever #link1 is clicked.
  $('.brand a').on('click', function () {
      $('.nav li:first').addClass('active');
      $('.nav li:first').siblings('li').removeClass('active');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you should only have one active element on the page, you could do something like this.

```
  $('.nav li a').on('click', function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  });
```

If not then you can use `closest` like so

```
  $('.nav li a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  });
```

From your comment i think this could work

```
  $('.nav li a').on('click', function() {
    $('active').removeClass('active');
    var link = $(this).attr('href'), // link1
        number = parseInt(link.substr(-1)), // 1
        newHref = link.slice(0, link.length - 1) + number++;
    $(newHref).addClass('active');

  });
```

so if you click on `link1` then `link2` will get the active class and click on `link2` then `link3` will get it and so on....

Comment: First suggestion works exactly like my initial script. 2nd suggestion makes link2, link3 and link4 all active at once.

I need link1 (which is not an li or under nav class) to make link2 active when clicked.